# Expandable menu with jQuery - animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a menu that expands the subcategories on hover - so only one subcategory can be expanded at a time.  It will looks something like this (completely expanded):

- X

  - Y

    - Y.1
    - Y.2
  - Z

    - Z.1
    - Z.2

My issue is this:

The animation works correctly, except if I hover over Y and then try to hover over Z, all of X closes. I know why: there needs to be a delay because Z starts moving up, so you're no longer hovering on Z and it starts closing.

Below is the code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#m2l2").hoverIntent(
            function() {
                clearTimeout(z_timer);
                $("#m2l2").toggleClass("child childopen");
                $("#u12").slideToggle("slow", "linear");
            },
            function() {
                z_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#u12").slideToggle("slow", "linear", function () {
                        $("#m2l2").toggleClass("childopen child");
                    });
                }, 10000);
            });
    });
```

Is there any way to avoid a delay or to make a delay that only activates in certain case?

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/XYp48/12/

Thank you!!!

Comment: for start, i think `click` event is better than `hover`

Comment: i will see your code, and if i can, i will solve your problem ;)

Comment: If you can do it with pure CSS it will be much better :)

Comment: thanks so much! i actually just updated the JSFiddle - this is the latest code: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/XYp48/2/

Comment: and would you do it with CSS just by modifying the heights? i tried that but found that i needed to modify the height of the external menu div and i couldn't access it with CSS.

Comment: why you want do it with `hover` ? it isnt user friendly

Comment: in the context of the entire site, i think it is fairly user friendly actually, though i can definitely explore the possibility of clicking. i'll take a look at that, but if it's clicking, I would need the bullet points to be clickable and the links to still work.

Comment: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/XYp48/3/

Comment: if it is what you want, i will add some features to that

Comment: and convert it for `hover` mod

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/XYp48/6/

Comment: oh that looks awesome, thanks! i will do some research to see if i can make the bullets clickable only. though i do still think i want to stick with hovering. the format of the site is pretty firmly set, so i can't change much and i don't think clicking would work with the way the menu looks.

Comment: If you still want to use hover rather than click, is it okay if your list item ui changed a bit, here's what it looks like if you want http://jsfiddle.net/XYp48/7/

Comment: thanks! though i do want to keep the general format, so i probably won't be able to use your code - but still really helpful to look at so thank you! i've actually figured out my issue..now i just have to figure out a way to solve it actually. changed the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to add timeout for hoverIntent by using the object from [hoverIntent jQuery Plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

```
$('.selector').hoverIntent({
    over: function(){},
    out: function(){},
    timeout: 1000 // in miliseconds
});
```

so here's what it will look like : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XYp48/14/), even though sometimes it takes to long before the out function called, so define it with whatever best usage for your case

Comment: thank you so much for the help! this is exactly what i needed :) probably should've spent a little more time investigating the hoverIntent plugin....

Comment: if your problem is solved, please mark as your accepted answer, so other that come with the same problem could know what to do :)

Comment: Even after giving timeout the issue is coming in JSfiddle demo

Comment: what issue still coming in JSfiddle demo? it's working for me. and what did you do to make the issue come?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the js code issue but css issue, you have a vertical menu where 3rd level also opens vertically.

**Its tricky but try to visualize**

When your mouse enters option Y its 3rd level menu shows ,now when you take mouse on option Z the mouseout event for Y fires and it hides its 3rd level due to which position of option Z shifts and now your mouse pointer is outside the main menu #id="m2l0" and its mouseout event fires and hides both options Y and Z.

Comment: Add a statement console.log("out of main menu"); in $("#m2l0") mouseout handler and you will understand what i am saying. I think you should try with click event instead of hover as in your case handling mousein/mouseout scenarios will be very tricky.